# Parsing JSON from HTTPResponse

Tags: java, json, httpresponse, arrays

My JSON looks like this-

```
{"ipinfo": {
    "ip_address":"4.2.2.2",
     "ip_type":"Mapped",

                "Location":{

                            "continent":"north america",

                            "latitude":33.499,

                            "longitude":-117.662,

                        "CountryData":{

                                "country":"united states",

                                "country_code":"us"},

                        "region":"southwest",

                        "StateData":{

                                "state":"california",

                                "state_code":"ca"},

                        "CityData":{

                                "city":"san juan capistrano",

                                "postal_code":"92675",

                                "time_zone":-8}}

    }}
```

This is my below code which tries to access members of items in a JSONArray

```
    try {
        String url = service + version + method + ipAddress + format;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.getRequestLine();
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            for (String line = null; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            //Exception getting thrown in below line
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        bufferedReader.close();
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

I am always getting exception thrown at this line-

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
```

Below is the exception getting thrown

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1
```

Can anyone suggest me what wrong I am doing in my code? And how can I improve it?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty accurate. the JSON you posted has no arrays, just plain objects.  JSON syntax is at http://json.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used that particular API, but judging by the fact that the object is named `JSONArray` (keyword: array) I'm going to guess it expects an array. Using JSON, an array has to begin with a `[` and end with `]`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It can contain objects:

```
[{}, {}, {}]
```

Note how the objects begin with `{` and end with `}`, unlike the arrays:

```
{
    "name": "My Object!"
}
```

Since your JSON data looks more like an `{object}` than an `[array]` maybe you should try using [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) instead.

Really though you have two options: you can change the JSON data to be an array, or you can change the Java code to use `JSONObject`. (One or the other; NOT both.)

## Changing the JSON data

As simple as adding a `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end:

```
[
    {
        "ipinfo": {
            "ip_address": "4.2.2.2",
            "ip_type": "Mapped",
            "Location": {
                "continent": "north america",
                "latitude": 33.499,
                "longitude": -117.662,
                "CountryData": {
                    "country": "united states",
                    "country_code": "us"
                },
                "region": "southwest",
                "StateData": {
                    "state": "california",
                    "state_code": "ca"
                },
                "CityData": {
                    "city": "san juan capistrano",
                    "postal_code": "92675",
                    "time_zone": -8
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

## Changing the Java

The final Java would look a little something like:

```
// OLD CODE
//JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
//for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
//    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//}
// END OLD CODE
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
```

---

(Again, one or the other; NOT both.)

Comment: @TechGeeky - Out of curiosity, which of the two solutions did you use?

Comment: It really depends on what you needed. Based on what you stated in the question, no one solution is better than the other... but if there were other factors - for example, if you were consuming 3rd party JSON and couldn't change the JSON data - then there might be a right choice and a wrong choice.

Answer (score 2):

Your source JSON is just a single object. Instead of loading into an array, loading straight into a `JSONObject` should suffice.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
```

This object will have a single property named `ipinfo`.